# angular reactive pattern for only numbers with + and #

Tags: javascript, regex, angular, angular-validation

I'm working on reactive form with postal code control it allows only `+` and `#` only  with numbers. Max length for the controls is 10. I tried with following code even i enter the valid value it still shows the error.

ts

```
postalCode: ['', {
  validators: [
    Validators.required,
    Validators.pattern('/^(?=.*[0-9])[+#()0-9]+$/')
  ], 
  updateOn: 'blur'
}],
```

View

```
<input type="text"
       class="form-control"
       id="postalCode"
       formControlName="postalCode"
       maxlength="10">

<div class="error-msg"
     *ngIf="driverForm.controls.postalCode.hasError('pattern')">
  <span class="red-star"> patter Error </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove quotes from regex

Instead of

```
'/^(?=.*[0-9])[+#()0-9]+$/'
```

Use without `'` quotes

```
/^(?=.*[0-9])[+#()0-9]+$/
```